# How to create a new post from React/Axios via the WordPress Rest API

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, rest, post, axios

Hoping someone can shed some light on this for me. I am working with React and Axios to try and create a new post via the Wordpress Rest API. I am using a WP plugin, JWT and react-cookies to handle the auth token and store in a cookie (which is working) but my second POST to actually create the new post is getting a 401 (Unauthorized) error.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
const loginData = {
  username:user,
  password:pass
}


axios.post( '/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',loginData)
.then( res => {
  console.log(res.data.data);
  setCookie('apiToken', res.data.data.token);
});

axios( '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: 'New Blog Post'
    }),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.apiToken}`
    }
} ).then( res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your apiToken is set or not when you are making second post request? Probably apiToken is undefined. So before making 2nd post req make sure your apiToken is set.

Comment: Hi Mahmud, I did and it is being set/stored and passing to the var just fine.